# kml refresh on zoom in/ zoom out

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to load a simple kml (1 ko) into my map.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: '@url'
        });
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

The problem is that every time i zoom in /out the layer is refreshed and we see the map without the layer for very few seconds . 
Is there any way to keep the kml loaded and avoid that?

Comment: You can compare your code with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml it seems the sample code also refresh the layer if you zoom in / zoom out, I think that is the way it adjust the layer based on the map sizes.

Comment: you are right i was looking for a trick but obviously there isn't ! thank you !